# PageUnit problems

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm trying to do some 2D drawing in C# using the GDI+ primitives and I'm having some problems:

```
protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e )
{
    Graphics dc = e.Graphics;
    dc.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimiter;
    dc.DrawLine( 0f, 50f, 100f, 50f );
    base.OnPaint( e );
}
```

This piece of code should draw a 10 cm line, but I always get a line of 10.6/7cm. If I use pixels as unit, and try to draw a 96 pixel ( that should be 1inch line), I get a 1.1inch line.
Am I doing something wrong, or it's just something that I cannot fix?
Various info: I'm using VS2010 SP1 and on VS2005 and on MFC C++ if I draw a 5cm line, I got a line of 5cm.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you measuring this with a ruler?  Monitor DPI is never accurate.

Comment: Actually yes, in my MFC C++ program I also used a mm unit and I have much more accurate results, that's why I'm asking...